# Player keeps gettings stuck on game object in 2D tile based scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid, 2d

I am creating a 2D grid based game in Unity. I am using Tile maps for background (one grid and two tile maps).
On the first tile map I have the background (like grass) and on the second one I have things I add, like a hole in the ground. Now I add game objects to the scene (a sprite tree). I have two BoxCollider2D on the tree, first one is just a small one at the bottom of the tree and the other one covers the whole tree but is set as trigger (I have a script that automatically fades out the tree when user is behind it).

The problem is that the user keeps getting stuck at the collider (I think) at the bottom of the tree. It works from some angles. I tried creating a small 2D square too and sometimes I get stuck to that too. What am I missing?

I have added a custom material that has friction set to 0 on both the Player and the tree.

I don't know if it is relevant but the tree is quite big so I had to set its size to 0.5 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

remove the interaction between the player and the tree, see in project setting, modify the script to work with a raycast

or just make the tree collider a Trigger..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).